# Upload Excel file to servlet and get data from it

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi

I'm trying to upload excel file to a servlet, get data from it and then send this data to a database.

And I'm stuck at the very beginning: uploading the file.

To get data from the file, I want to use Apache POI, and here is my code:

```
System.out.println("entered Import.java");
Part filePart = request.getPart("import"); 
System.out.println("filePart: "+filePart);

FileInputStream inputStream = (FileInputStream) filePart.getInputStream();
System.out.println("inputStream: "+inputStream);

Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);

Sheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);

for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        System.out.println("row: "+row+", cell value: "+cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
    }
}
inputStream.close();
```

The output of this code is:

```
entered Import.java
filePart: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart@bc6f13
inputStream: java.io.FileInputStream@532048c5
Servlet.service() for servlet [Import] in context with path [/Management] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root causejava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions
```

The UI part is SAPUI5 framework and [here it is](http://jsbin.com/falopilada/1/edit?js).

I looked through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985809/upload-read-an-excel-file-in-a-jsp-using-poi) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet) threads, but it didn't help me.

How do I get this servlet to work?

Comment: Did you try to import the class you are missing? It says it doesn't have the XmlOptions class. You can find it in this jar : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmlbeansxmlpublic240jar.htm.  Try to import it and try again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the jars in your web application which are containing the XmlOptions class.

See the following reply in ([java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024193/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-xmlbeans-xmloptions)).

Comment: well, this is embaressing for me. Thank you.