# How to get the data from Excel sheet into out jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp-tags

I tried to read an excel file and display it in a jsp page, i use this code below but it get an error message.

Code:

```
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<html>
<table border="1">
<%
 short a=0;
  short b=1;
  short c=2;
  short d=3;
  int i=0;
   String   value1="", value2="",value3=" ", value4="";
    String filename ="a.xlsx"; 
    if (filename != null && !filename.equals("")) {
    try{
    FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    for (int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
    int j=i+1;
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
    int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
    HSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r);
    int     cells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); 
    out.write("<br>");
    HSSFCell cell1  = row.getCell(a);
      value1 = cell1.getStringCellValue();
      HSSFCell cell2  = row.getCell(b);
        value2 = cell2.getStringCellValue();
         HSSFCell cell3  = row.getCell(c);
         value3 = cell3.getStringCellValue();
          HSSFCell cell4  = row.getCell(d);
          value4 = cell4.getStringCellValue();
    %>
    <tr><td><%=value1%></td><td><%=value2%></td><td><%=value3%></td><td><%=value4%></td></tr>
    <%
    }
        i++;
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    }
    %>
    </table>
    </html>
```

Error message

> HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:  type Exception
>   report message Unable to compile class for JSP:  description The
>   server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling
>   this request. exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to
>   compile class for JSP:  An error occurred at line: [14] in the
>   generated java file:
>   [C:\Users\Vu\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\jpsexcel\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported. org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet
>   resolves to a package
>
> An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file:
>   [C:\Users\Vu\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\jpsexcel\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported.
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook resolves to a package An
>   error occurred at line: [16] in the generated java file:
>   [C:\Users\Vu\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\jpsexcel\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported. org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow
>   resolves to a package An error occurred at line: [17] in the generated
>   java file:
>   [C:\Users\Vu\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\jpsexcel\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported. org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell
>   resolves to a package An error occurred at line: 20 in the jsp file:
>   /index.jsp HSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type 17:     if
>   (filename != null && !filename.equals("")) { 18:     try{ 19:
>   FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename); 20:
>   HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs); 21:     for (int k = 0; k <
>   wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){ 22:     int j=i+1; 23:     HSSFSheet
>   sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k); An error occurred at line: 20 in the jsp
>   file: /index.jsp HSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type 17:     if
>   (filename != null && !filename.equals("")) { 18:     try{ 19:
>   FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename); 20:
>   HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs); 21:     for (int k = 0; k <
>   wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){ 22:     int j=i+1; 23:     HSSFSheet
>   sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
>
> An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /index.jsp HSSFSheet
>   cannot be resolved to a type 20:     HSSFWorkbook wb = new
>   HSSFWorkbook(fs); 21:     for (int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets();
>   k++){ 22:     int j=i+1; 23:     HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
>   24:     int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); 25:     for (int
>   r = 0; r < rows; r++){ 26:     HSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r); An
>   error occurred at line: 26 in the jsp file: /index.jsp HSSFRow cannot
>   be resolved to a type 23:     HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k); 24: 
>   int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); 25:     for (int r = 0; r
>   < rows; r++){ 26:     HSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r); 27:     int
>   cells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();  28:     out.write("
> ");
>   29:     HSSFCell cell1  = row.getCell(a);
>
> An error occurred at line: 29 in the jsp file: /index.jsp HSSFCell
>   cannot be resolved to a type 26:     HSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r);
>   27:     int     cells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();  28:
>   out.write("
> "); 29:     HSSFCell cell1  = row.getCell(a); 30:
>   value1 = cell1.getStringCellValue(); 31:       HSSFCell cell2  =
>   row.getCell(b); 32:         value2 = cell2.getStringCellValue(); An
>   error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /index.jsp HSSFCell cannot
>   be resolved to a type 28:     out.write("
> "); 29:     HSSFCell
>   cell1  = row.getCell(a); 30:       value1 =
>   cell1.getStringCellValue(); 31:       HSSFCell cell2  =
>   row.getCell(b); 32:         value2 = cell2.getStringCellValue(); 33:
>   HSSFCell cell3  = row.getCell(c); 34:          value3 =
>   cell3.getStringCellValue(); An error occurred at line: 33 in the jsp
>   file: /index.jsp HSSFCell cannot be resolved to a type 30:
>   value1 = cell1.getStringCellValue(); 31:       HSSFCell cell2  =
>   row.getCell(b); 32:         value2 = cell2.getStringCellValue(); 33:
>   HSSFCell cell3  = row.getCell(c); 34:          value3 =
>   cell3.getStringCellValue(); 35:           HSSFCell cell4  =
>   row.getCell(d); 36:           value4 = cell4.getStringCellValue();
>
> An error occurred at line: 35 in the jsp file: /index.jsp HSSFCell
>   cannot be resolved to a type 32:         value2 =
>   cell2.getStringCellValue(); 33:          HSSFCell cell3  =
>   row.getCell(c); 34:          value3 = cell3.getStringCellValue(); 35: 
>   HSSFCell cell4  = row.getCell(d); 36:           value4 =
>   cell4.getStringCellValue(); 37:     %> 38:
>   <%=value1%><%=value2%><%=value3%><%=value4%>
>   Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/8.0.26 logs.

Comment: The error says clearly: "Only a type can be imported. org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook resolves to a package"

Answer (score 1):

[Upload+ read an excel file in a jsp using POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985809/upload-read-an-excel-file-in-a-jsp-using-poi)

You can check this issue for read data from excel file with jsp.

İf I were you I'll research how to handle excel sheet with jsp and handle it. After that I create backend java object for read data from sheet and send the sheet from jsp to backend java object.

Comment: i've read that topic before, but it dosen't work. I am a newbie, i dont know much about it.

Comment: I couldn't find any free time today. If I could, I'll give short example about this issue for you. Now first you should research "How to select programmatically excel file with jsp" after that you handle file and sen to backend java code for parsing the excel.