# Why does not load infomation from excel (*.xlsx) (use Apache POI)?

Tags: java, excel, jsp, apache-poi

Try to load information on JSP from Excel file (*.xlsx) use Apache POI 3.15.

View information in excel

**num   solution**

1   First

2   Second

3   Third

try to use code

```
try {
        InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("C:\\server\\to_db.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);

        XSSFWorkbook test = new XSSFWorkbook();

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row;
        XSSFCell cell;

        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();

                if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " ");
                } else if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + " ");
                } else {
                    //U Can Handel Boolean, Formula, Errors
                }
            }
            out.println("Succefully!!!");
        }
    }
     catch (Exception e) {
    out.println( "exception: "+e);
    }
```

Getting a strange result:

> absent error and absent information on JSP....

Problem problem is reproduced in all browsers.
If I try open C:\server\to_db.xlsx OS Windows responce "File is busy".
What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a `FileInputStream` or `FileOutputStream`, you need to close it otherwise your file could be locked by the process according to the OS used especially on Windows OS. More generally speaking, you need to `close` all `Closeable` objects that you use to prevent any leaks or issues like this one.

So you should rewrite your code as next to use the [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) statement that will automatically close the resources for you.

```
try (InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("C:\\server\\to_db.xlsx");
     XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead)) {
   ...
```

Indeed in your code you have 2 `Closeable` objects which are `ExcelFileToRead` and `wb`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to close the file using ".close() ". [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985809/upload-read-an-excel-file-in-a-jsp-using-poi) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

In lib directory absent some commons libs

commons-collections4-4.1.jar, commons-codec-1.10.jar, commons-fileupload-1.3.jar

their presence solved problem.